# Parameter that depends on a Decision in MSF

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, constraint-programming, ms-solver-foundation

In Microsoft Solver Foundation, I'd like to know if it's possible to add a parameter who's value depends on a decision value.

I.e. I want something to the TSP model, but it should also take in account traffic from one point to the other. Please note: traffic depends on the time when the sales man travels on that route.

Here is the model:

I have a matrix of all possible combinations between the cities.

The Decision variable is the `Order` of the sales man's route. 0 is the first, 1 second,...

I have a property `timeToTravel` which is bound to a property that calculates the time when the route will take place from the `Order` value and it returns the travel time including traffic for that time of the day.

It seems to me that the parameter values are read once and cached when the `Solve` function is called, am I correct? If yes, does anybody have any recommendations to solve this problem?

*Originally I asked this question [on the MSF forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/solverfoundation/thread/54a1ad6a-dc9e-4040-81ec-604a5f999cfb) but I thought it would get more attention on Stack Overflow. Also I'm open to different solvers other than MSF but I'd prefer to stay in the .NET environment.*

Comment: Is the theory for this specific TSP problem established?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on solving the "static" Traveling Salesman Problem using Solver Foundation [here](http://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/solving-traveling-salesman-problems-using-solver-foundation/). If you do not already have your own implementation, maybe you can base your solution on that code.

This is the goal formulation from the mentioned article:

```
// Goal: minimize the length of the tour.
Goal goal = model.AddGoal("TourLength", GoalKind.Minimize,
    Model.Sum(Model.ForEach(city, i => 
        Model.ForEachWhere(city, 
            j => dist[i, j] * assign[i, j], j => i != j))));
```

If I understand correctly, in your problem the time to travel between two cities is dependent on the time-of-the-day?

I do not believe you can dynamically update the `dist[,]` `double` array during the optimization. However, using the building blocks of the [Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model%28v=vs.93%29) class it should be possible to reformulate the `dist[,]` array as a set of functions that are dependent on the total distance/time already traveled.

For completeness, [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.se/2009/03/tsp-in-oml-ms-solver-foundation.html) is another interesting article on TSP formulation using OML.